# Pygame Gun Rotating Up sight Down On The Left Side Problem

Tags: python, pygame

so I have this gun here where it rotates towards my mouse x, and mouse y position but the problem ([VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/3ea7b5dc21328756372c7f2d305d6280)) is the gun turns upside down. Is there a way I could make the image of my gun not upside down and do the same movement as my gun facing the right side? Like the gun for the left side is upside down for some reason and I don't have an idea on how to do this at all

Gun Image:

[image]

```
my gun draw(self)

    def draw(self,drawX,drawY):

        self.rect.topleft =  (drawX,drawY)

            # the gun's hitbox

            # rotating the gun
        dx = self.look_at_pos[0] - self.rect.centerx
        dy = self.look_at_pos[1] - self.rect.centery 
            
        angle = (180/math.pi) * math.atan2(-dy, dx)
      
        gun_size = self.image.get_size()
        pivot = (8, gun_size[1]//2)
            

        blitRotate(window, self.image, self.rect.center, pivot, angle)

    def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
            
        self.look_at_pos = coordinate
```

my full gun class

```
class handgun():
    def __init__(self,x,y,height,width,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,height,width)


        # LOL THESE IS THE HAND
        self.shootsright = pygame.image.load("hands.png")
        self.image = self.shootsright
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        self.look_at_pos = (self.x, self.y)

        self.isLookingAtPlayer = False
        self.look_at_pos = (x,y)
            



        self.hitbox = (self.x + -18, self.y, 46,60)



    def draw(self,drawX,drawY):

        self.rect.topleft =  (drawX,drawY)

            # the gun's hitbox

            # rotating the gun
        dx = self.look_at_pos[0] - self.rect.centerx
        dy = self.look_at_pos[1] - self.rect.centery 
            
        angle = (180/math.pi) * math.atan2(-dy, dx)
      
        gun_size = self.image.get_size()
        pivot = (8, gun_size[1]//2)
            

        blitRotate(window, self.image, self.rect.center, pivot, angle)

    def lookAt( self, coordinate ):
            
        self.look_at_pos = coordinate
```

this is where the rotation happens like how my gun will rotate:

```
def blitRotate(surf, image, pos, originPos, angle):

        # calcaulate the axis aligned bounding box of the rotated image
    w, h = image.get_size()
    sin_a, cos_a = math.sin(math.radians(angle)), math.cos(math.radians(angle)) 
    min_x, min_y = min([0, sin_a*h, cos_a*w, sin_a*h + cos_a*w]), max([0, sin_a*w, -cos_a*h, sin_a*w - cos_a*h])

        # calculate the translation of the pivot 
    pivot        = pygame.math.Vector2(originPos[0], -originPos[1])
    pivot_rotate = pivot.rotate(angle)
    pivot_move   = pivot_rotate - pivot

        # calculate the upper left origin of the rotated image
    origin = (pos[0] - originPos[0] + min_x - pivot_move[0], pos[1] - originPos[1] - min_y + pivot_move[1])

        # get a rotated image
    rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(image, angle)

        # rotate and blit the image
    surf.blit(rotated_image, origin)
```

my full code: [script](https://pastebin.com/25s5Z60C)
andy help is appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mirror the gun image once it turns past 90 degrees anti-clockwise from the positive x-axis.
You can do this using pygame.transform.flip() which takes in three parameters:

1. The surface objects (In this case, your gun image)
2. Whether the image should be flipped horizontally (No)
3. Whether the image should be flipped vertically (Yes)

So you'll want to have a variable which indicates where the gun is facing:

```
gunDirection = "right"
```

And also code which will flip the image whenever the gun changes direction:

```
if(angle > 90 and gunDirection != "left"):
    gunDirection = "left"
    self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, False, True)
if(angle < 90 and gunDirection != "right"):
    gunDirection = "right"
    self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, False, True)
```

This should all be in the gun class, if you're using radians the angle would be 0.5pi

Comment: I am not sure why its not working [my gun class](https://pastebin.com/ETY4TWJM)

Comment: In your case, it should be done like this: https://pastebin.com/Y3rbsLsY

Comment: I tested it with that code and the gun flips around to stay upwards whenever it points in the opposite direction

Comment: Here is the solution pasted into your program: https://pastebin.com/Y25zQLAe